# Fedora suddenly started using ugly fonts

Tags: linux, fedora, fonts, kde, kde-plasma-5

I'm having an issue with Fedora (or KDE, not sure). Fedora, as the tittle says, started to use ugly fonts on some apps, suddenly (Opera, Code Editors, IntelliJ, etc.) I don't know if it's a KDE issue or a Fedora issue, although I consider it's KDE because I had never experienced this with Fedora/Gnome. I hope you know what's the problem, and thank you for your help. By the way, this didn't happened after any update.

Comment: Currently, I don't have a screenshot, but, for example, consider apps use the font you see on the comments, right here, but, suddenly,  the apss started to use something like a 'serif' font, really ugly one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

1. **Install RPMFusion Repository**:

   ```
   su -c 'dnf install http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm'
   ```
2. **Install freetype-freeworld**

   `apt-get install freetype-freeworld`
3. Use nano to open /etc/fonts/local.conf
   and paste the next code:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
   <fontconfig>
   <match target="pattern">
   <test compare="eq" name="family" qual="any">
   <string>Arial</string>
   </test>
   <edit binding="same" mode="assign" name="family">
   <string>Noto Sans</string>
   </edit>
   </match>
   <match target="pattern">
   <edit name="dpi" mode="assign">96</edit>
   </match>
   <match target="font">
   <edit mode="assign" name="antialias" >
   <bool>true</bool>
   </edit>
   </match>
   <match target="font">
   <edit mode="assign" name="hinting" >
   <bool>true</bool>
   </edit>
   </match>
   <match target="font">
   <edit mode="assign" name="hintstyle" >
   <const>hintslight</const>
   </edit>
   </match>
   <match target="font">
   <edit mode="assign" name="rgba" >
   <const>rgb</const>
   </edit>
   </match>
   <match target="font">
   <edit mode="assign" name="lcdfilter">
   <const>lcddefault</const>
   </edit>
   </match>
   <alias binding="strong">
   <family>sans-serif</family>
   <prefer>
   <family>Open Sans</family>
   </prefer>
   </alias>
   <alias binding="strong">
   <family>serif</family>
   <prefer>
   <family>Bitstream Charter</family>
   </prefer>
   </alias>
   <alias binding="strong">
   <family>monospace</family>
   <prefer>
   <family>Source Code Pro</family>
   </prefer>
   </alias>
   </fontconfig>
   ```
4. Reboot Your OS